# Biztalk Flat File Schema Wizard: Parsing config files

Tags: biztalk, flat-file

I have several config files that may or may not have certain attributes.

For example:

```
Property1 : value1
Property2 : value2
.
junk text
junk text : line count between useful data varies in every file.
junk text
.
Property3 : value3 //optional
```

Is there a way to only retrieve the properties by Tag Identifier only, and skip all the junk in between?

So far, I cannot figure out how to make skip the junk.  "Ignore" is only allowed after "Record Sequence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like the below, where you tell it to look for certain tags, and have records without tags to consume those you aren't interested in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.Junk" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.Junk" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Root" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="complexity" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Property1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="Property1 :" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="value1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Property2">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="Property2 :" sequence_number="2" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="value2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Junk">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="3" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="JunkValue" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Property3">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="Property3 :" sequence_number="4" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="value3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MoreJunk">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="5" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="JunkValue" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```